# React loader spinner is not showing on Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql

When a user registers it should show the spinner and send them to the dashboard page. I have it set to 8 seconds to allow plenty of time for backend but it still doesn't show. Below is the code.I have state set and using a useeffect setting a timeout and a ternary operator to navigate to the dashboard in the jsx

```
const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation CreateUser($userInput: UserInput!, $profileInput: ProfileInput) {
    createUser(userInput: $userInput, profileInput: $profileInput) {
      token
      userId
      tokenExpiration
    }
  }
`;

const Register = (props) => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setTimeout(() => {}, 8000);
  },[]);

  //dont need context yet
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  function loginUserCallback() {
    login();
  }

  //1. record values from input here
  //2. send it in empty, and hook returns with k/v pairs
  const { onChange, onSubmit, values } = useForm(loginUserCallback, {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    dob: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    bio: "",
    occupation: "",
  });

  //3. separate values
  //replace with values.email... etc
  const userInput = {
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password,
    firstName: values.firstName,
    lastName: values.lastName,
    dob: values.dob,
    city: values.city,
    state: values.state,
  };

  const profileInput = {
    bio: values.bio,
    occupation: values.occupation,
  };

  const [login, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER, {
    update(proxy, { data: { createUser: userData } }) {
      context.login(userData);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    },
    onError({ graphQLErrors }) {
      setErrors(graphQLErrors);
    },
    //4. send as variables to backend
    variables: {
      userInput: userInput,
      profileInput: profileInput,
    },
  });

  if (loading) {
    <h1>error loading</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Dashboard />}

      <img
        src="https://floatui.com/logo.svg"
        width={150}
        className="mx-auto"
        alt="logo"
      />
      <div className="text-center font-semibold font-serif mt-4">REGISTER</div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="email" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            Email
          </label>
          <input
            name="email"
            type="text"
            placeholder="email"
            id="email"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            required
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="password" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            name="password"
            type="text"
            placeholder="password"
            id="password"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2  bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="firstName" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            First Name
          </label>
          <input
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            placeholder="firstName"
            id="firstName"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="lastName" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            lastName
          </label>

          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="lastName"
            id="lastName"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="Date of Birth" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            Date of Birth
          </label>

          <input
            name="dob"
            type="date"
            placeholder="dob"
            id="dob"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="city" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            City
          </label>

          <input
            name="city"
            type="text"
            placeholder="city"
            id="city"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="state" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            State
          </label>

          <input
            name="state"
            type="text"
            placeholder="state"
            id="state"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="occupation" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            Occupation
          </label>

          <input
            name="occupation"
            type="text"
            placeholder="occupation"
            id="occupation"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="max-w-md px-4 mx-auto mt-12">
          <label htmlFor="state" className="block py-2 text-gray-500">
            Bio
          </label>

          <textarea
            name="bio"
            type="text"
            placeholder="bio"
            id="state"
            rows="4"
            col="50"
            className="w-full mt-2 px-3 py-2 text-gray-500 bg-transparent outline-none border focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg"
            onChange={onChange}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <button className="mt-5 px-6 py-2 text-white duration-150 bg-indigo-600 rounded-lg hover:bg-indigo-700 active:shadow-lg">
            REGISTER
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include details relevant to routes and routing, and what the actual issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the spinner is not showing up is because the `loading`variable from `usemutation` is not correctly handled.

In the code, the `loading` variable is destructured from the `useMutation` hook as follows:

const [login, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER, {...})

However, when you check if `loading`is`true` in the return statement, you do not return any component or text. Instead, you just have a comment. Therefore, even though the loading variable may be `true`, no spinner is actually displayed.

To fix this, you should return a `loading` spinner, such as:

```
 if (loading) {
      return <Loading />;
    }
```

This will cause the `Loading` component to be displayed while the mutation is being processed.

Additionally, in the `useEffect` hook, you are not actually doing anything after the 8-second timeout. To display the spinner for 8 seconds, you should update the `useEffect` hook as follows:

```
    useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, 8000);
}, []);
```

This will change the value of `isLoading` to `false` after 8 seconds, causing the `Dashboard` component to be displayed.

Overall, your `Register` component should look something like this:

```
    const Register = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 8000);
  }, []);

  const { onChange, onSubmit, values } = useForm(loginUserCallback, {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    dob: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    bio: "",
    occupation: "",
  });

  const userInput = {
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password,
    firstName: values.firstName,
    lastName: values.lastName,
    dob: values.dob,
    city: values.city,
    state: values.state,
  };

  const profileInput = {
    bio: values.bio,
    occupation: values.occupation,
  };

  const [login, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER, {
    update(proxy, { data: { createUser: userData } }) {
      context.login(userData);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    },
    onError({ graphQLErrors }) {
      setErrors(graphQLErrors);
    },
    variables: {
      userInput: userInput,
      profileInput: profileInput,
    },
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Dashboard />}

      <img
        src="https://floatui.com/logo.svg"
        width={150}
        className="mx-auto"
        alt="logo"
      />
      <div className="text-center font-semibold font-serif mt-4">REGISTER</div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        ...
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```